# How to re-write polls application built in django tutorials in django documentation using django.forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have built the polls application given in Django tutorials under Django documentation. How to recreate polls page where user could vote for a question, using Django forms?

Please note:

My Question & Choice Model remains unchanged. However I want to create the form to submit votes for a question using django.form (not ModelForms).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And what have you tried?

Comment: While learning Django through these tutorials I understood the concept of creating forms and linking them in HTML. However, while reading the Django Docs further I came accross Forms concept, which I'm unable to understand clearly. I have tried building up a form to display choices for a Question posted in the polls app. However, I hit a roadblock while getting the choices for a particular question and displaying it in the form.

Comment: But this is not something you would do. If you want to create a form based on a model, you would use a ModelForm.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I'll read more on ModelForms and try to implement it.